# Matrix elements sum

Tags: javascript, matrix

I want to get the sum of the matrix elements, except for those over which the number 0, and get error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
let s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= matrix.length; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            matrix[i+1][j] = 0;
        }
        s += matrix[i][j]
    }
}
return s
}
console.log(matrixElementsSum([[0, 1, 2, 0], 
                               [0, 3, 2, 1], 
                               [2, 0, 2, 3]]))
```

Comment: it is probable that 'i' or 'j' are not correct and that index does not exits

Comment: Your outer loop should iterate till the number of rows and the inner loop should iterate till the number of columns.

Comment: now I understand everything, thanks))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop counter i should iterate over number of rows and j should iterate over number of columns. Also before setting `matrix[i+i][j]` to 0, you should also check if `i+1 < matrix.length` (number of rows)

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    let s = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0 && i+1 < matrix.length) {
                matrix[i+1][j] = 0;
            }
            s += matrix[i][j]
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem. Hope it would help someone.

```
function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
    let susp = [];
    return matrix.reduce((t, arr, i)=>{
        return arr.reduce((tt, val, ii)=>{
            if (val === 0) susp.push(ii);
            if (susp.includes(ii)) {
               return tt;
            } else {
               return tt+val;
            } 
        }, 0) + t;
    }, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with Python:

```
def solution(matrix):
    row_len = len(matrix)
    col_len = len(matrix[0])
    sum = 0
    
    for c_index in range(col_len):
        for r_index in range(row_len):
            if matrix[r_index][c_index] == 0:
                break
            else:
                sum += matrix[r_index][c_index]
        
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(matrix) {
let sum= 0;

for (let i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        if (matrix[j][i] === 0) break;
        sum+= matrix[j][i];
    }
}

return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(matrix) {
  for(var r=0,j=0;j<matrix[0].length;j++){
      for(var i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
        if(matrix[i][j]===0) break
        else r+=matrix[i][j]
      }
  }
  return r
}
```

It took me some time to solve this exercise. I see it was not very complicated.